# run java script in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, v8

I'm trying to use R to run javascript from a webpage. and create internal variables in R. I could do this with web drivers like selenium but I want to this with javascript engine v8 from inside R instead of from a browser instance. However, I cannot create a `window` object in the V8 engine. Here is my code to read and evaluate javascript in a page:

```
library('rvest')
library("V8")
library("dplyr")
url <- 'https://google.com'
webpage        <- read_html(url)
script         <- html_nodes(webpage,'script') %>% html_text %>% paste(collapse = "\r\n")
ct <- v8()
ct$eval(src = script)
```

in javascript code, they referred to internal dom objects like `document`, `body` and etc. which I don't care about them, but I cannot run the rest of the code; I'm getting error like `ReferenceError: the document is not defined`. is there any way to create a dummy `window` object in V8 engine independent from the browser? or even better determine to skip any line than you cannot execute?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to create a dummy window object in V8 engine independent from the browser?

Of course, you can implement a dummy `window` object in JavaScript (regardless of which engine you're using, V8 or any other):

```
window = window || this;
window.document =  ...;
window.location =  ...;
window.setTimeout = function(...) {...};
window.... = ...;  // etc.
```

or you can look for an existing library that has already done all this work (it's a lot of work!) for you. Use your favorite search engine.

That does make me wonder, though, whether the tools you've chosen are the most suitable tools for the job. There is a fairly wide gap between pure ECMAScript as implemented by V8, and the whole DOM/browser interaction stuff that's available to and used by scripts on websites.

> or even better determine to skip any line than you cannot execute?

No; V8 does not have such a mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response. while I looked for a pure javascript library to mock the window object. I did not find any useful one; if you know the one I appreciate to post it here. and Implementing window objects by myself is out of my scope. I was looking for a shortcut!

Comment: Define "useful". https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom seems pretty full-featured; though I have no personal experience with it. There's a fairly long list with alternatives at https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers#fake-browser-engine.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to run a javascript with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://www.google.com/"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
doc <- IEApp$document()
doc$parentWindow()$ExecScript("alert('yep, it worked!')")
```

You could use the R package RSelenium with the same approach.